# JSON_ERROR when adding Symfony app

Tags: php, json, symfony, centos, php-7

I just installed Symfony on my CentOS setup running with PHP 7.0.14. I am however having the following issue when trying to run `symfony new project_name`:

```
    PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant JSON_ERROR_DEPTH - assumed 'JSON_ERROR_DEPTH' in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 134
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH - assumed 'JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH' in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 134
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR - assumed 'JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR' in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 134
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX - assumed 'JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX' in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 134
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant JSON_ERROR_UTF8 - assumed 'JSON_ERROR_UTF8' in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 134
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function json_decode() in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php:142
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Message/Response.php(145): GuzzleHttp\Utils::jsonDecode('{"lts":"2.8.18"...', true, 512, 0)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/src/Symfony/Installer/NewCommand.php(127): GuzzleHttp\Message\Response->json()
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/src/Symfony/Installer/NewCommand.php(65): Symfony\Installer\NewCommand->checkSymfonyVersionIsInstallable()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(259): Symfony\Installer\NewCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(878): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 phar:///us in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 142
```

I've checked around the web for answers, and have already tried setting `phar.readonly = Off` in php.ini

Comment: how did you installed php 7 ? seems that you are missing json extension , or need to enable it;

Comment: You were right, @hassan, I was missing the JSON-exstension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hassan was right, I was missing the json-extension. Fixed it by running `sudo yum install php70u-json`