# Symfony 3.4 bug php json during install

Tags: php, json, symfony, php-5.6

During symfony install with

> symfony new my_project 3.4

I have this error:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant JSON_ERROR_DEPTH - assumed 'JSON_ERROR_DEPTH' in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 140
>   PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH - assumed 'JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH' in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 140
>   PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR - assumed 'JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR' in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 140
>   PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX - assumed 'JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX' in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 140
>   PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant JSON_ERROR_UTF8 - assumed 'JSON_ERROR_UTF8' in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 140
>   PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function json_decode() in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 142

My PHP is:

> PHP 5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli) 
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

Do you know how to help me?

Comment: Just a guess but maybe the [json extension](http://php.net/manual/en/json.setup.php) is not installed for some strange reason.

Comment: as a note: if you are using multiple php version user `php5.6-json` if not `php-json` as php extension name when you want install it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON\_ERROR when adding Symfony app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140962/json-error-when-adding-symfony-app)

Comment: i have installed php5.6-json, restart pc but same error remain. I'm doing not in a server but on my pc, that can be a problem? I presume not.

Answer (score 0):

Try `php -m` in a terminal to see if php5.6-json is correctly loaded

Then `php --ri json | grep version` if you want to check the module version

Comment: result of php -m is:
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

and php --ri json | grep version have no result

Comment: but if I try apt-get install php5.6-json the result is that php5.6-json is already installed and updated.

Comment: So with this you are on the good way to resolve your issue, json module is not loaded even if you have installed it

Comment: Try also php  - v - - ini to see which php ini file is loaded and try to enable the json module if you are sure you have installed it